# GitHub API Merge Pull Request (Merge Button) Not Found Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api

I'm trying to use the Github [Merge Pull Request (Merge Button)](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button) but when I call it in either Postman or my app, it gives me a response of 404 Not Found, even though I'm know the `:owner`, `:repo` and `:number` is correct.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge
```

Anybody has have this issue? and how to solve it or correctly call the API endpoint?

This is my code

```
const MergeOpenPR = async (owner, repo, token, number, sha) => {
  const url = `${ROOT_API_URL}/repos/${owner}/${repo}/pulls/${number}/merge?access_token=${token}`;
  let body;

  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sha,
      }),
    });
    body = res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error);
  }

  return body;
};
```

Comment: Besides what Petar mentioned (GitHub experiencing some issues), are you sure your access token has the right permissions? In [an issue for a different problem](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/935) in a project that uses the GitHub api, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the case, as I haven't tried to push anything to my github repo since this morning, but I've read somewhere that GitHub is experiencing some issues and that they've set it to **read-only** mode, so maybe, although not entirely sure, that causes your problem, since you said you are sure your `:owner`, `:repo` and  `:number` are correct. Maybe try again later or tomorrow.

EDIT: Heres a link for GitHub status, currently isn't working properly.
https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: Thanks. I know they are/were having issues, but didn't know they had set it to read-only mode.